# How to retrieve the properties stored in SQL with multiple inheritance

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression, multiple-inheritance

I'm storing the records in SQL that represent a multiple inheritance relationship similar to the one in C++. Like that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Classes 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Inheritance 
(
    class_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    base_class_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (class_id) REFERENCES Classes(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (base_class_id) REFERENCES Classes(id)
);
```

The classes have properties of two types. These properties are inherited by the classes, but in different ways. The first type type of property whenever defined for the class *overrides* the value of the same property used in any of base classes. The other type *accumulates* the value: the property is actually a set of values, each class inherits all values of it's base classes, plus may add an additional (single) value to this set:

```sql
CREATE TABLE OverridableValues
(
    class_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    value TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (class_id) REFERENCES Classes(id)
);

CREATE TABLE AccumulableValues
(
    class_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    value TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (class_id) REFERENCES Classes(id)
);
```

The caveat with `OverridableValues`: there are no cases when the same property is overridden on different paths of multiple inheritance.

I'm trying to design queries using common table expressions that would return the value/values for a given property and class.

The approach that I'm trying to use is to start from the root (assume for simplicity that there is a single root class), and then to build the tree of paths from the root to every other class. The problem is how to pass the information about properties from the parents to children. For example below is an incorrect attempt to do that:

```sql
WITH ParentProperty (id, value) AS 
(
    SELECT c.id, a.value
    FROM Classes c
    LEFT JOIN AccumulableValues a
      ON a.class_id = c.id
    WHERE c.id = 1 --This is the root

    UNION ALL

    SELECT i.class_id, IFNULL(a.value, ba.value)
    FROM ParentProperty p
    JOIN Inheritance i
      ON i.base_class_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN AccumulableValues a
      ON a.class_id = i.class_id
    LEFT JOIN AccumulableValues ba
      ON ba.class_id = i.base_class_id
)
SELECT id, value
FROM ParentProperty;
```

I feel like I need one more `UNION ALL` inside the CTE, which is not allowed. But without it I either miss proper values or inherited ones. So far I've failed to design the query for both types of properties.

I'm using SQLite as my database engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution. I'm describing it below, but more efficient ones are still welcomed.

Let's start with the *Accumulable* property. My problem was that I tried to add more than one `UNION ALL` into a single CTE. I've solved that with adding additional CTE (see the `AcquiresFrom`)

```sql
WITH AcquiresFrom (class_id, from_class_id, value) AS
(
    SELECT a.class_id, a.class_id, a.value
    FROM AccumulatableValues a

    UNION ALL

    SELECT i.class_id, i.base_class_id, NULL
    FROM Inheritance i
),
ClassProperty (class_id, value) AS
(
    SELECT c.id, NULL
    FROM Classes c
    LEFT JOIN Inheritance i
      ON i.class_id = c.id
    WHERE i.base_class_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.class_id, IFNULL(a.value, p.value)
    FROM ClassProperty p
    JOIN AcquiresFrom a
      ON (a.from_class_id = p.class_id AND a.from_class_id != a.class_id) OR
         (a.class_id = p.class_id AND a.class_id = a.from_class_id AND p.value IS NULL)
)
SELECT DISTINCT class_id, value
FROM ClassProperty
WHERE value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY class_id;
```

The `AcquiresFrom` means the way to aquire the value: the class either introduces a new value (the first clause) or to inherits it (the second clause). The `ClassProperty` incrementally propagates the values from base classes to derived. The only thing left to do is to eliminate duplicates and `NULL` values (the last clause `SELECT DISTINCT` / `WHERE value IS NOT NULL`).

The overridable property is more complex.

```sql
WITH Roots (id, value) AS
(
    SELECT c.id, o.value
    FROM Classes c
    LEFT JOIN Inheritance i
      ON i.class_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN OverridableValues o
      ON o.class_id = c.id
    WHERE i.base_class_id IS NULL
),
PossibleValues (id, acquired_from_id, value) AS 
(
    SELECT r.id, r.id, r.value
    FROM Roots r

    UNION ALL

    SELECT i.class_id, CASE WHEN o.value IS NULL THEN p.acquired_from_id ELSE i.class_id END, IFNULL(o.value, p.value)
    FROM PossibleValues p
    JOIN Inheritance i
      ON i.base_class_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN OverridableValues o
      ON o.class_id = i.class_id
),
Split (class_id, base_class_id, direct) AS (
    SELECT i.class_id, i.base_class_id, 1
    FROM Inheritance i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i.class_id, i.base_class_id, 0
    FROM Inheritance i
),
Ancestors (id, ancestor_id) AS (
    SELECT r.id, NULL
    FROM Roots r

    UNION ALL

    SELECT s.class_id, CASE WHEN s.direct == 1 THEN a.id ELSE a.ancestor_id END
    FROM Ancestors a
    JOIN Split s
      ON s.base_class_id = a.id
)
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.value
FROM PossibleValues p
WHERE p.acquired_from_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT a.ancestor_id
    FROM PossibleValues p1
    JOIN PossibleValues p2
      ON p2.id = p1.id
    JOIN Ancestors a
      ON a.id = p1.acquired_from_id AND a.ancestor_id = p2.acquired_from_id
    WHERE p1.id = p.id
);
```

The `Roots` is obviously the list of classes that have no parents. The `PossibleValues` CTE propagates/overrides the values from roots to final classes, and breaks multiple inheritance cycles making the structure a tree-like. All valid id/value pairs are present in the result of this query, however some invalid values are present as well. These invalid values are those that were overridden on one of the branches, but this fact is not known on another branch. The `acquired_from_id` allows us to reconstruct who was that class that first introduced this value (that may be useful whenever two different classes intruduce the same value).

The last thing left is to resolve the ambiguity caused by multiple inheritance. Knowing the class and two possible values we need to know whether one value overrides the other. That is resolved with the `Ancestors` expression.